# Prove that each of the following sets, with the indicated operation, is an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

$1.$ $x * y = x + y + k$ ($k$ a fixed constant), on the set $\mathbb R$ of the real numbers.

$x * y = x + y + k = y + x + k = y * x.$ Commutativity holds.

$(x * y) * z = (x + y + k) * z = (x + y + k) + z + k = (z + y + k) + x + k =x * (y * z).$ Associativity holds.

$x * e = x + e + k = x,$ so $e = -k.$ Further, $e * x = -k + x + k = x.$ Thus $e$ is an identity.

$x * x' = x + x' + k = e,$ so $x' = e  - x -k.$ Further, $x' * x = e  - x - k + x + k = e.$ Thus, $x'$ is an inverse element.

This set is an Abelian Group.

$2.$ $x * y = \frac {xy}{2}, \text { on the set } \{x \in \mathbb R: x \neq 0\}.$

$x * y = \frac {xy}{2} = \frac {yx}{2} = y * x.$ Commutativity holds.

$(x * y) * z = (\frac {xy}{2}) * z = \frac {(xy)z}{2} = \frac {x(yz)}{2} = x * (y * z).$ Associativity holds.

$x * e = \frac {xe}{2} = x,$ so $e = 2.$ Further, $e * x = \frac {2x}{2} = x.$ Also, $e = 0$, but this identity doesn't hold for the elements in the domain. Thus, $e$ is an identity.

$x * x' = \frac {xx'}{2} = e,$ so $x' = \frac {2e}{x}.$ Further, $x' * x = \frac {\frac {2e}{x}x}{2} = e.$ Inverse exists.

This set is an Abelian Group.

$3.$ $ x * y = x + y + xy, \text { on the set } \{x \in \mathbb R: x \neq —1 \}.$

$ x * y = x + y + xy = yx + x + y = y * x$. Commutativity holds.

$ (x * y) * z = (x + y + xy) * z = (x + y + xy) + z + (x + y + xy)z = x + y + xy + z + xz + yz + xyz = x + (y + xy + z) + x(z + xy) + yz.$ Associativity fails.

$ x * e = x + e + xe = x,$ so $x = -1.$ Further, $e * x = e - 1 - e = -1.$ So, $e$ holds for $x = -1$. This element is not in the domain. There's no identity in this this set and therefore this set is not a group.

$4.$ $x * y = \frac {x + y}{xy + 1}$ on the set $\{x \in \mathbb R: -1 < x < 1\}.$

$x * y = \frac {x + y}{xy + 1} = \frac {y + x}{yx + 1} = y * x.$ Commutativity holds granted $xy \neq -1.$

$(x * y)* z= (\frac {x + y}{xy + 1})* z = \frac {(x + y) + z}{(xy + 1)z + 1)} = \frac {(x + (y + z)}{x(yz + \frac zx) + 1}.$ Associativity fails.

$x * e = \frac {x + e}{xe + 1} = x,$ so $e = x({xe + 1}) - x = x^2e,$ so $x = \sqrt{1}$ and $x = -\sqrt{1}.$ Further, $e * x = \frac {e + \sqrt{1}}{e\sqrt{1} + 1} = 1.$ First $e$ doesn't hold for all the elements in the set. Second, $1$ is not even in the set. No identity here. This set is not a group.

Just checking my work.

Comment: @ sanjab, so $e = -x - k$. So, $e * x = -x - k + x + k = x$ which is not true, so there's no identity and therefore no inverse in that set. Does it work?

Comment: For $4.$, didn't you divide by $e$? What about the possibility that $e=0$? (and you don't need to say "granted that $xy\neq -1$" just above, since for $x,y$ in the set you have $\lvert xy\rvert < 1$, so a product equal to $-1$ cannot happen). And yoour second equality for the associativity check of $4.$ is wrong.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra you were correct, I made a mistake

Comment: but in point 3. I am not sure why associativity fails. it looks like it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1) Everything is fine, though it might be nice to explicitly say what the inverse is - you have it as $x'=e-x-k=-x-2k$ since you know $e=-k$.

Problem 2) There's a slight error on the proof of associativity: In the middle it should be $\frac{(xy)z}{4}=\frac{x(yz)}{4}$. Note the new denominator. Again here it might be nice to explicitly write the inverse as $x'=\frac{4}{x}$.

Problem 3) Why did you conclude that associativity fails? In fact it holds. Here from your equation you should be testing the identity $e=0$, not $x=-1$. After you've done this you will need to check for inverses, and probably you have to check the special case when $x'=-1$.

Problem 4) You should redo your associativity check - there's a mistake in the computation. Again, with your equation for $e$ here, you should conclude $e=0$. Again this leads you down the road of having to check for inverses.

Comment: About associativity in $3$, in $(x + y + xy) + z + (x + y + xy)z  = x + (y + xy + z) + x(z + xy) + yz$, the $4$th set of parentheses is missing the third term. That's why I concluded that associativity fails. Can you, please, explain why that doesn't fail associativity and what actually would fail associativity?

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra I agree with you computation: $(x*y)*z=x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+xyz$, but also $x*(y*z)=x*(y+z+yz)=x+(y+z+yz)+x(y+z+yz)=x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+xyz$ which is the same as before. I'm afraid I can't tell what you mean when you say the $4$th parenthesis is missing.

Comment: A case which fails associativity is $x*y=\frac{x}{y}$. You have $(x*y)*z=(\frac{x}{y})*z=\frac{x}{yz}$, but $x*(y*z)=x*(\frac{y}{z})=\frac{xz}{y}$.

Comment: If $e = 0$ in $3$, then it holds for all elements in the domain. So, there's an identity in this set. Also, just so I am not solving the wrong problem, is $x' = \frac {e - x}{x - 1}$?

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra I think the equation is a little wrong - I got an $x+1$ instead of $x-1$ in the denominator. You can also see now why $-1$ was excluded from the domain - because we are dividing by $x+1$ which is $0$ when $x=-1$ and dividing by $0$ is a problem. The reason I said that you need to check the case $x'=-1$ is that $-1$ isn't in the domain, so the $x$ which would have an inverse of $-1$ would now have no inverse. However, it's not too hard to find that $x'=-1$ is not possible (you multiply out the equation and then see that if $x'=-1$ then $e=-1$ which is not true).

Comment: @ Peter Woolfitt, $ x' * x = \frac {- x}{x + 1} + x + x \frac {- x}{x + 1} = \frac {- x}{x + 1}(1 + x) + x = 0$ as expected. Now to the $4$th problem.

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra Yep, that looks good

Comment: @ Peter Woolfitt, $(x * y)* z= \frac {(\frac {x + y}{xy + 1}) + z}{(\frac {x + y}{xy + 1})z + 1 } = \frac {\frac {x}{xy + 1} + \frac {y}{xy + 1} + z}{\frac {xz}{xy + 1} + \frac {yz}{xy + 1} + 1 }$ 

and $x * (y * z) = \frac {x + (\frac {y + z}{yz + 1})}{x(\frac {x + y}{yz + 1}) + 1 } =  \frac {\frac {y}{yz + 1} + \frac {z}{yz + 1} + x}{\frac {x^2}{yz + 1} + \frac {yz}{yz + 1} + 1 }$ Does it look good so far?

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra In the denominator for $x*(y*z)$, I think it should be $\left(\frac{y+z}{yz+1}\right)$ instead of $\left(\frac{x+y}{yz+1}\right)$

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra And after that, all you need to do is multiply both numerator and denominator by $xy+1$ in $(x*y)*z$ and by $yz+1$ in $x*(y*z)$ to get a simpler form, and then you can see that these are actually the same.

Comment: @ Peter Woolfitt, Let $e = 0.$

Let $x' =  - \frac {e - x}{(ex - 1)}$

Then $x' * x = \frac {- {\frac {e - x}{(ex - 1)} + x}}{{- \frac {e - x}{(ex - 1)}x + 1}}  = 0.$ Looks like this set has an inverse element. Sorry, it took me so long - I am at work and it's a constant distraction :)

Comment: @AbstraktAlgebra That looks correct to me, and it's no problem as I'm glad to help :).